# Access variable in @BeforeTest and @AfterClass (TestNG) across separate classes?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am writing some selenium automated UI tests for my company using Java and the TestNG framework.  I am defining the driver in a `Base` class, and I want to actually initialize the driver in an `@BeforeTest` and quit it in a `@AfterTest` method.  What is the Java way to do that, assuming they are in different classes?  I know how to make it work in the same class, but not over separate classes.  Here is my `Base.java` file:

```
public class Base {

        public static WebDriver driver = null;
        public WebDriver getDriver() {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            return driver;
        }
}
```

Now, I want to have a separate Setup class and a separate Teardown class.  If I was going to define all of this in the same `@Test`, I would do it this way:

```
@Test
public void testOne() {

    Base b = new Base();
    WebDriver driver = b.getDriver();

    // Do test-y things here. 

    driver.quit();
}
```

How would I set this up?  Trying to learn the right way to do this, and not hack something together.  I can also provide more information if needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use inheritance.

```
public class TestBase {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("I am in setUp method.");

        //WebDriver instantiation etc.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized", "--disable-cache");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        System.out.println("I am in tearDown method.");

        //You can clean up after tests.
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

And then inheritance can be used. Pay attention to the `extends` keyword:

```
public class ParticularTest extends TestBase {

   @Test
   public void testMethod() {
       System.out.println("I am in testMethod.");

       //Your driver from TestBase is accessible here.
       //Your assertions come here.
   }
}
```

Later on you can just execute `ParticularTest.java`.
Output:

```
I am in setUp method.
I am in testMethod.
I am in tearDown method.
```

Comment: Thanks!  Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you please DONOT resort to this mechanism of instantiating webdrivers in your tests. `@BeforeTest` by definition is expected to be invoked **ONLY ONCE** per `<test>` tag. So if your TestNG suite xml file has something like this

```
<test name="MyTests">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.foo.Test1"/>
        <class name="com.foo.Test2"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

and if both `com.foo.Test1` and `com.foo.Test2` extend your `TestBase` class, then the `@Test` methods within your `com.foo.Test2` class are bound to hit a `NullPointerException` when accessing your `driver` object because your `@BeforeTest` annotated `setup()` method within `TestBase` will be executed only once (for `Test1`) and it will **NOT** be executed for `Test` since both the classes extend from the same base class.

I would suggest that you please resort to something like [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/) (this is my blog) to do web driver instantiations.

Comment: Actually, I did end up doing something similar to that.  I have a Base class that actually instantiates the driver, and then then I extend the Base class with the TestBase class containing my Before and After Tests, and then extend THAT class to the actual test classes.  It's working very well so far!

Comment: I have changed my `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` annotations to `@AfterClass` and `@BeforeClass`. Now there is no `NullPointerException` in your example. Giving you an upvote though, cause it is the first time I see  composition over inheritance implemented in TestNG on your blog.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz - Using a BeforeClass/AfterClass is good but still it has a few issues. (1) Since al the test methods will now end up using the same class level data member webdriver, these test methods cannot run in parallel (2) Even if tests run in sequential order, if a test method pollutes the browser in terms of cookies etc., the downstream test methods will be impacted. (3) So you could definitely consider moving towards instantiation & cleanup of browsers via BeforeMethod/AfterMethod and persist the webdriver instance into a ThreadLocal variant so that there are no race conditions.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan. AD 1. Wouldn't it be enough to persist the WebDriver into a ThreadLocal in my code to go parallel? AD 2. For some tests it may be useful to use the same browser (e.g. log into a website only once and perform many tests, each one in another method). AD 3. I have read your article and left a comment there.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz - As long as you are persisting the webdriver instance into the proper test method's context, you should be fine (And that happens only when you do it either via a beforemethod/aftermethod combo (or) via a beforeInvocation/afterInvocation combo because these are the only two set of things that are guaranteed to run on the same thread as a test method. In terms of using the same browser for doing many tests, sure it makes sense, but you just need to be aware that u lose parallelism. Yes I saw your comment and responded too. Hashcode is unique as long as its not overridden.