# Some of the methods of TestNG Parent class are not running

Tags: java, testng

I have a Parent class `BaseClass` with `TestNG` annotations as below

```
public class BaseClass 
{
     protected static WebDriver driver; 

     @BeforeSuite
     public void beforeSuite()
     { 
       System.out.println("\nBEFORE SUITE : "); 
     }

     @BeforeTest
     public void launch() throws IOException
     {
       //CODE TO LAUNCH BROWSER
     }

     @BeforeClass
     void beforeclass()
     {
       System.out.println("BEFORE CLASS");  
     }

     @AfterClass
     void afterClass()
     {      
       System.out.println("After test ");
     }

     @BeforeMethod
     void beforeMethod()
     {
       System.out.println("BEFORE METHOD ");    
     }

     @AfterMethod 
     void afterMethod ()
     {  
       System.out.println("After METHOD ");
     }

     @AfterSuite
     void afterSuite()
     {
       System.out.println("\n After Suite");
     }
}
```

and the `child class` extending it as below

```
public class SearchQualityRuleTest extends BaseClass
{
    @Test
    public void searchTest() throws InterruptedException  
    {
      //Assertions 
     }  
}
```

My XML file is as below

```
<suite name="AAD-AED suite" verbose="1" >
    <test name="AED tests">
      <classes>
             <class name="tests.AED_searchQualityRuleTest"/>          
      </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Other than `@BeforeSuite` and `@BeforeTest` methods no other methods are running.

I have code related to `Extent Reports` in other non executed methods.

Please suggest if there is any mistake in the code

Comment: When i edit your code, semi-colon were missing from the `System.out.println` statement. Can you please re-check again this issue with my edited code?

Comment: I have made changes to code and replaced with S.O.P lines  just to make it simple to evaluate. but in my project I haven't missed semicolon.

Comment: Now, it is working well for you right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than meets the eye.
Output of your example on my computer:

```
BEFORE SUITE : 
BEFORE CLASS
BEFORE METHOD 
After METHOD 
After test 

 After Suite
```

I bet you have got more classes, which inherit from `BaseClass`, not just one.
Those methods are not executed properly due to reasons similar as behind [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002745/4280359). Implementing an `InvokedMethodListener` would help you to overcome issues with inheritance.

Comment: yes, you are right there are so many classes taking instance of the webDriver defined in BaseClass. will try using "InvokedMethodListener" and let you know thankyou

Comment: @PravallikaEsarla, if this answer was helpful, how about upvoting/accepting? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Include BaseClass in your testng.xml

<suite name="AAD-AED suite" verbose="1" >
    <test name="AED tests">
      <classes>
             <class name="tests.AED_searchQualityRuleTest"/> 
             <class name="tests.AED_BaseClass"/>
      </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).