# @AfterClass of parent class is not being called in TestNg child class

Tags: testng

```
        I  have a similar issue as reported in this [post]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988473/access-variable-in-beforetest-and-afterclass-testng-across-separate-classes/77764575#77764575][1]
and need help to understand if my code needs any restructuring.  The issue is for the second test SeleniumDragnDrop, the browser does not close. 
        parent class
        ------------
        package selenium.setup;
        
        import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
        
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
        import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
        import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
        import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
        import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
        
        public class SeleniumBaseTest {
            protected final static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<> 
            ();
                
            @BeforeClass
            @Parameters({"browser","baseURL"})
            public void Setup(String browser, String baseURL) throws Exception{
                webDriver.set(BrowserManager.doBrowserSetup(browser));
                System.out.println("Before Test Thread ID: 
                "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                //get URL
                webDriver.get().get(baseURL);
                webDriver.get().manage().window().maximize();
                webDriver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
                webDriver.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, 
                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        
            @AfterClass
            public void tearDown(){
                webDriver.get().quit();
                System.out.println("After Test Thread ID: 
                "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                webDriver.remove();
            }
        }`
        
        Child class
        -----------
        `package selenium.trials;
        
        import java.time.Duration;
        
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
        import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
        import org.testng.ITestContext;
        import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
        import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;
        
        import selenium.setup.SeleniumBaseTest;
        import selenium.utils.WebElementUtility;
        
        public class SeleniumDragnDrop extends SeleniumBaseTest{
            Logger logger;
            WebDriver driver;
            
            @BeforeTest(alwaysRun=true)
            public void beforeTest(ITestContext testContext){
              logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
              driver = webDriver.get();
              
              logger.info("In dragNDrop beforeTest: Thread ID: 
              "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
            
            @Test
            public void dragNDrop() throws InterruptedException {
                logger.info("In dragNDrop Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                
            WebElementUtility.clickOn(driver,driver.findElement(By.linkText("Drag and 
            Drop")), Duration.ofSeconds(15));
                
            WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id("column-a"));
            WebElement dest = driver.findElement(By.id("column-b"));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.dragAndDrop(source, dest).build().perform();
            logger.info("After dragNDrop Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
            
            @AfterTest
            public void tearDown() {
            logger.info("In dragNDrop tearDown : Thread ID: 
            "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        }`
        
    package selenium.trials;
    
    import java.awt.AWTException;
    import java.time.Duration;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.testng.ITestContext;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    import selenium.setup.SeleniumBaseTest;
    import selenium.utils.WebElementUtility;
    
    public class SeleniumAlerts extends SeleniumBaseTest{
        Logger logger;
        WebDriver webDriver;
        
        @BeforeMethod
        public void beforeTest(ITestContext testContext){
          logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
          //webDriver = driver.get();
          logger.info("In testAlerts beforeMethod: Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
          logger.info(" Driver " + driver.get().getCurrentUrl());
        }
        
        @Test
        public void testAlerts() throws InterruptedException {
            logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
            logger.info("In testAlerts Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            //driver = webDriver.get();
            
            try {
            WebElementUtility.clickOn(driver.get(),driver.get().findElement(By.linkText("JavaScript Alerts")), Duration.ofSeconds(15));
            }catch(org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(" current URL  " + driver.get().getCurrentUrl());
                WebElementUtility.clickOn(driver.get(),driver.get().findElement(By.linkText("JavaScript Alerts")), Duration.ofSeconds(15));
            }
            
            WebElement ele = driver.get().findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Click for JS Alert']")); 
            WebElementUtility.clickOnAlert(driver.get(),ele, Duration.ofSeconds(20),true);
            
            WebElementUtility.clickOnAlert(driver.get(),driver.get().findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Click for JS Confirm']")), Duration.ofSeconds(20),false);
            clickOnPrompt(driver.get(),driver.get().findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Click for JS Prompt']")), Duration.ofSeconds(20),false);
            logger.info("In testAlerts Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            //driver.get().quit();
        }
        
        @AfterMethod
        public void setDown() {
            logger.info("In testAlerts setDown : Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
            //driver.get().quit();
        }
        testng.xml
        ---------
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
        <suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="classes">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <parameter name="baseURL" value="https://the-internet.herokuapp.com"/>
        
        <test name="SeleniumTrials"  preserve-order="true">
            <classes>
                <class name="selenium.trials.SeleniumDragnDrop"/>
                <class name="selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
        </suite>
        
       log4j.xml
----------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Properties>
    <Property name="basePath">./logs</Property>
    
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %-5logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        
    </Console>
    
    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${basePath}/selenium.log" filePattern="${basePath}/automation-%d{yyyy-MM">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %-5logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50000"/>
    </RollingFile>
    
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have a parent class that instantiates WebDriver and child classes having @Test methods using the driver class.

The issue is for the second test SeleniumDragnDrop, the browser does not close. Debugging shows me that the @AfterClass is not getting called. It's also evident from the fact that the logger.info for this test is not logged. Log trace below. @BeforeClass is called

```
17:23:40.558 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-1] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumDragnDrop - Before Class: Setup Thread ID: 23
```

No logging appears for  After Class. See this log trace.

```
   Log -
        ---
        
        17:23:0.015 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-2] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts - Before Class: Setup Thread ID: 23
        17:23:36.591 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-2] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts - Before Class: Setup Thread ID: 24
        17:23:40.558 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-1] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumDragnDrop - Before Class: Setup Thread ID: 23
        17:24:15.498 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-2] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts - In testAlerts beforeMethod: Thread ID: 24
        17:24:15.518 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-2] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts -  Driver https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/
        17:24:19.681 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-2] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts - In testAlerts Thread ID: 24
        17:24:23.108 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-1] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumDragnDrop - In dragNDrop beforeMethod: Thread ID: 23
        17:24:23.112 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-1] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumDragnDrop - In dragNDrop Thread ID: 23
        17:24:28.017 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-1] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumDragnDrop - After dragNDrop Thread ID: 23
        17:24:28.019 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-1] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumDragnDrop - In dragNDrop setDown : Thread ID: 23
        17:24:40.756 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-2] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts - In testAlerts Thread ID: 24
        17:24:40.760 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-2] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts - In testAlerts setDown : Thread ID: 24
        17:24:55.176 [TestNG-test=SeleniumTrials-2] INFO  selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts - After Class: Setup Thread ID: 24
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that test SeleniumDragnDrop had @AfterTest method which was closing the session. Hence @AfterClass was not called. After removing @AfterTest its working fine